# Summary column with conditional if in r

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, apply

I want to have summary column with these conditions:

- If part 1 greater than part 2 & 3 than give value 1
- If part 2 greater than part 1&3 than give value -1
- If part 3 greater than part 1&2 than give value 0
- If two part has same greater value give 0
- If NA give value NA

Code:

```
    df <- structure(list(id.Var1 = c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
    "B", "C", "D"), id.Var2 = c("B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", 
    "E", "E", "E"), Part1 = c(NA, 0, 0, 60, 100, 0, 20, 50, 20, 
     80), Part2 = c(NA, 60, 100, 0, 0, 100, 20, 50, 20, 0), Part3 = c(NA, 
     40, 0, 40, 0, 0, 60, 0, 60, 20)), row.names = c(37L, 73L, 74L, 
    109L, 110L, 111L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse`:

```
df%>%
   mutate(res=case_when(
     Part1>Part2 & Part1>Part3~1,
     Part2>Part1 & Part2>Part3~-1,
     Part3>Part1 & Part3>Part2~0,
     Part3==Part2 | Part1==Part2 | Part1==Part3~0,
     is.na(Part3) | is.na(Part2) | is.na(Part1)~NA_real_
   ))
   id.Var1 id.Var2 Part1 Part2 Part3 res
1        A       B    NA    NA    NA  NA
2        A       C     0    60    40  -1
3        B       C     0   100     0  -1
4        A       D    60     0    40   1
5        B       D   100     0     0   1
6        C       D     0   100     0  -1
7        A       E    20    20    60   0
8        B       E    50    50     0   0
9        C       E    20    20    60   0
10       D       E    80     0    20   1
```

Comment: Simply write `is.na(Part1) ~ NA_real_` to remove this line `ifelse(res==9,NA,res)`. Check the manual `"# All RHS values need to be of the same type. Inconsistent types will throw an error.
# This applies also to NA values used in RHS: NA is logical, use
# typed values like NA_real_, NA_complex, NA_character_, NA_integer_ as appropriate."`

Comment: Oh, it's simple with tidyverse. Thanks jyjek. And I've just knew about using ~ NA_real_ Thank you Jimbou

Answer (score 1):

Some of the conditions seem redundant, e.g. if Part1 > Part2 then the two cannot be equal, and if either Part1 or Part2 is greater than Part3 (first two conditions) then Part3 cannot be greater than Part1 or Part2 (third condition). So you might simply do

```
with(df, (Part1 > Part2 & Part1 > Part3) *  1 + 
         (Part2 > Part1 & Part2 > Part3) * -1 )
# [1] NA -1 -1  1  1 -1  0  0  0  1
```

Gives the same result as jyjek's `dplyr` code.

Comment: Yes this one also possible. Thanks lebatsnok